# Discord.py how do I send a DM to anyone I want through a command

Tags: python, discord

Someone asked me to make a bot for him that sends a DM to anyone he specifies through a command, like `*send_dm @Jess#6461 hello`.

I've searched alot and I came across this code:

```py
async def send_dm(ctx,member:discord.Member,*,content):
    await client.send_message(member,content)
```

but then I got the error:

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'send_message'

I want to type for example : `*send_dm @Jess#6461 hello` and the bot sends a DM saying "hello" to that user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`client.send_message()` has been replaced by `channel.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#sending-messages) in the version 1 of discord.py

You can use [`Member.create_dm()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.create_dm) to create a channel for sending messages to the user

```
async def send_dm(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, content):
    channel = await member.create_dm()
    await channel.send(content)
```

Comment: then I got this error:
`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'channel' is not defined`

Comment: can I also do that I can put any user I want, even though it isn't in the server?

Comment: Probably, try using the `User` class

Comment: Then when I do `*send_dm <@330368617084616714> hello` it gives me an error that user doesnt exist:
`discord.ext.commands.errors.BadArgument: User "<@330368617084616714>" not found`

Comment: @wotman In `discord.Member` you need to mention a member.

Answer (score 0):

HI there hope this help you

```
client.command(aliases=['dm'])
async def DM(ctx, user : discord.User, *, msg):
    try:
        await user.send(msg)
        await ctx.send(f':white_check_mark: Your Message has been sent')
    except:
        await ctx.send(':x: Member had their dm close, message not sent')
```

change you client if you use any other str

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do is:

```
async def send_dm(ctx,member:discord.Member,*,content):
  await member.send(content)
```