# name 'create_dm' is not defined

Tags: python, discord.py

How can I send messages to the users after they got kicked from servers? Whenever I try the following code, it doesn't work properly.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands  

intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True, reactions=True, members=True,presences=True,guild_messages=True)

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!dc ", intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():  
    print("I am ready!")

@client.command(aliases=["ban"])
@commands.has_role("admin")

async def ban_user(self,ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f"{member} has been kicked from server.")
    dm_channel = await create_dm(member)  #These two code lines are where I got this error
    await dm_channel.send("You've been banned from the server.You won't join the server until admin opens your ban.")
        
@commands.command(aliases=["kick"])
@commands.has_role("admin")

async def kick_user(self,ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f"{member} has been kicked from the server.")

client.run(myToken)
```

Comment: where is your create_dm function?

Comment: @AhmetBurak It is in the ban_user method.You can see,next to it,there is a comment which is '#These two code lines are where I got this error'

Comment: I saw that, I mean where you defined that function (probably not defined anywhere). Do you have a reference code?

Comment: @AhmetBurak ohh,okey I got your point.I use discord.py which is a module that help us to create discord bots.So,that create_dm funciton is defined in that module.But I couldn't figure out how to solve this problem

Comment: Just use `await member.send("Your ban message")` **BEFORE** you ban the member instead of `await dm_channel.send()`. You also use `self` just in cogs. If you do not have this in a `cog` get rid of `self` and just say `(ctx, ..)`

Comment: OK I didn't use discordpy, check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57340966/12306993

Comment: @Dominik Thanks dude it worked.By the way,I was using cogs,so there is a **self**.If you don't mind I want to know,why it worked because When I use **await member.send("Your ban message")** after I ban the member,it didn't work but your solution worked.Can you explain it?

Comment: @AhmetBurak Thank you,adamsın :)

Comment: @Dominik thank you so much :)I got it

Comment: @hARASİVa Once you ban the member, the bot will most likely no longer share a server with them so you have to send the message before the ban so that the bot can still either create a private message or send a message via `discord.member`. (*Corrected version of the comment before!*) - Happy coding! :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough . When something isn't working, "it doesn't work properly" is *not enough information*, and neither is a rough quote from an error message (which also makes a poor title for the question).

Answer (score 1):

According to your question, I am assuming that you want to dm the user who was banned. To do this you can,

```
async def ban(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await ctx.send(f'{member} has banned from the server.') # sends the message in the server
    await member.send(f'You have been banned from {member.guild.name}.') #dms the member that he has been banned.
    await member.ban(reason = reason) #bans the user from the server.
```

*Note: If you first ban the member, and then try to send the message in the server and dm, you will get an error as the member would not be found.*

Answer (score -1):

You can use the DMChannel function,
the code would look like this:

```
# put this on top:
from discord import DMChannel

# some stuff

async def ban_user(self, ctx, member: discord.Member=None, *, reason=None):
    if member is None: 

        # if the user don't inform a name to ban, returns this message:
        return await ctx.send(f'You need to inform which member you want to ban')
    
    # bans the user from the server:
    await member.ban(reason = reason)

    # sends the message in the server:
    await ctx.send(f'{member} has banned from the server.') 

    # dm the member 
    await DMChannel.send(member, f'You have been banned from {member.guild.name}.')
```

Comment: why not just use `member.send(f'You have been banned from {member.guild.name}.') `